# LSODA to dll - Fortran (F77) to dll to call from C#

Tags: c#, math, dll, fortran, numerical-methods

a little question in which I hope you can help me. (To make my life simpler)

One of the most respected numerical solvers for differential equations is LSODA, however it is written in Fortran... ( http://www.netlib.org/odepack/index.html )

There does not seem to be a decent solver for C#, and writing my own is too time consuming in C#, especially as I have very stiff equations that need to be solved.

The NAG libraries for net do not contain an ODE solver (they lack D02 routines). In terms of "university side" libraries that's it. 
However NAG Support suggested calling their dll, which is fine for simple variables, but has me rather perplexed with its external functions and dummy parameters which made me give up.

This leaves LSODA still, which is fortran, but a lot simpler in its calling sequence - so I wonder, how can the Odepack (the solvers that include the lsoda routine) be turned into a dll with little work, so that it may be called from C#?
(Which will leave me worried about the Jacobian, being a matrix, i.e. 2D array.)
Specifically, I would like a situation similar to that with the Fortran NAG library, but instead offering me access to lsoda: http://www.nag.co.uk/numeric/csharpinfo.asp

Please keep in mind that I am a mathematician - so if your responses loose me, please be patient with me. And why am I so focused on C# - well, it is simple, especially when one has VisualStudio 2010.

Many thanks for any responses in advance.

Comment: My advice would be to just use Fortran, but that's of course not a solution to your problem.  Strange that you use VisualStudio, I develop on linux for one big reason: no costs, great programming environment, and access to e.g. intel non-commercial compiler license.

Comment: But I don't want Fortran - which just doesn't seem to want to die. It means learning a programming language that is useless for anything but maths... Visual Studio - no, not strange normal. Linux: Please no if there is a better alternative (Windows) - (I don't really care about Linux, because I have no intention of using if I can avoid it. I have better things to do than to spend weeks to learn how to actually benefit from it.) And you are right, it isn't a solution, just a temporary patch.

Comment: it's ironic that you complain about Fortran not dying, while on the other hand you have no intention of writing a C# solver :)  Also, what will not benefit you in the end isn't the few days you'll spend on programming in fortran or so (it's basically just another syntax), it will be a lack of willingness to learn new (and actually not so different) things ;)

Comment: I don't have 6 months to a year to write a solver in C#. I actually wanted to write my own, but it is too time consuming. And "just another syntax" is easy to say for you. It isn't "just another syntax" for me. If there would be a suitable alternative, I would prefer to use it, but NAG has released their .net version without D02.

Comment: Building a dll from the odepack sources shouldn't be too difficult, but the specifics depend on the tools you're using. Basically, it's as simple as compiling each source file, and then linking them into a dll. I assume there are plenty of tutorials for your toolchain available to tell you how that is done.

Comment: @DetlevCM - Well, learn fortran then. My first handbook on it had no more than ... oh, I don't know ... 30 pages printed on one side. You can't tell me that's hard to go through ... btw, you don't mention what compiler are you using, but intel's and pgi's (maybe some other as well) come with vs integration/shell.

Comment: But it is still a waste of time. Besides the fact that I would need to stick the equations in by hand. Or delve deeper into it... and it still ignores the fact that Fortran should have died long ago. Intel's compiler does come with VS integration, but just not Visual Studio 2010. And while the university might buy me the newer version that does, I really can't see the point as to why they should spend I don't know how much on it. (US price is 700 Dollars, no idea about the UK.)

Comment: And just to add: I have Eclipse with a MinGW as a fortran compiler on my uni computer now... but it leaves me with the issue of sticking the equations in by hand... besides still having to figure out how it works exactly.

Comment: Yeah, don't you hate that, having to figure out how things work in order to use them. ;) Your opinion that Fortran should have died out is pointless. The fact is that many good Fortran libraries exist, and it doesn't take too much effort to use them from almost any other language. Wouldn't it be an enormous waste of effort to translate/rewrite them, not to mention the time it would take to iron out newly introduced bugs. A small investment in learning how to interface Fortran with your language of choice gives you easy access to many well tested, useful routines.

Comment: If I actually had LSODA as a dll (for all I care compiled from Fortran) I would be happy. The problem is, I can't just use Fortran code in C#. -> While I don't think calling Fortran dlls is perfect, not least because passing parameters is a mess, I'm willing to head down that route. BUT then I still need a dll, no?

Answer (score 1):

[SmartMathLibrary](http://smartmathlibrary.codeplex.com/) looks dead, but it claims to have ODEPACK bindings.  You could also check out Wikipedia's [List of .NET Numerical Packages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numerical_libraries#.NET_Framework_Languages_C.23.2C_F.23_and_VB.NET).

If you're open to other languages, Python's SciPy library contains a binding to LSODA: [enter link description here](http://www.scipy.org/doc/api_docs/SciPy.integrate.odepack.html).  It's available on Windows, easy to use, free, and widely embraced by the scientific community.

Comment: If it contains odepack that would be nice... but looking dead is often worrysome. I'll give it a consideration though - i.e. will try it. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, the odepack seems to be in C++ rather than C#.... it would mean I would need to migrate everything to Visual C++ from C#, but could be an idea...

Comment: Don't do it! It would probably be more work than creating a C# wrapper for ODEPACK.

Comment: Well, from the examples it seems that it can be called from C# - or VB, C++, etc.  However, I do wander, how is it's use intended? When you compile it, it compiles to a dll, does the developer aim the user to import functions from the dll or access them via their source code? It is has a very expansive help file with regards to function calls, but nothing on how to use it...

Answer (score 0):

It's not a full solution, but [f2c](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F2c) (Fortran-to-C converter) should be able to give you working C code from the Fortran source. That might at least be easier to get working from C#.

Disclaimer: I've never used f2c to convert a routine, I've only used some of the routines that someone else converted.